# How to hot deploy newly created files to Apache Tomcat in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, d3.js, build

I have a peculiar problem. I am extracting the data from a database in the form of `.csv` file and then passing this file to `d3.js` for visualization.

The problem is, `d3.js` doesn't allow `file://` based protocol (so I cannot give path to `.csv` file directly). The `.csv` file needs to be located on the server. But this file is generated on the run time.

I tried dumping the file in the same project folder, but as expected, the Eclipse doesn't take the updated file until next `clean` and `build` action.

Any idea how to work around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place the file in the place where your application is deployed on Tomcat (e.g.: Tomact7\webapps\myProject...), not in Eclipse Workspace location, this way your js can access the File either by its URL or relative path.

Comment: Yes of course I placed the file in the place where the application is deployed and not in Eclipse workspace. My concern is, I'm editing/creating this .csv file on the run time and I want to access this updated file on the fly. I am in search of a way where I can publish these changes automatically without manually doing clean and build every time

Comment: All what eclipse does in resources' files is to copy them from the Workspace to Tomcat app directory, if you create a file or change it at run-time while it is placed in tomcat app directory; it must be accessible at any moment through your application, I see no reason that prevents you from accessing the file if it is placed there.

Comment: I got the issue, Eclipse is refreshing the tomcat app directory only when i refresh the project folder in Eclipse ide manually. Since this file is created on the fly, it is not directly refreshed in IDE and hence it is not updated in the tomcat app directory. Is it okay to put this file directly to the tomcat app directory myself? I understand that i will lose this file if i deploy another version of the app, but i'm okay with it

Comment: Why not?, it's totally normal to create/modify/delete files on the app directory on the server itself as long it won't do any damage to the logic of your code.

Comment: Amazing, that really helped!